# Doubled time counting

Tags: javascript

After page load function "intro" is launch. This function displays two buttons, after click on one of them another function "startGame" starts with parameter "innerHTML" from click button. 
Then the right panel appears and "START" button counts time from 10. Countdown stops when user click on map or time reaches 0.
After "START" user can click on map (to add a marker) only ones, and click "START" again to add another marker.

When users click on map 4 times "game" finishes and two buttons appear again.

And that is when a problem starts. When function "startGame" starts again and user clicks "START" button, countdown doubles (you can see it in console).
If user clicks on map one countdown stops but second still counts to zero.

Can anyone tell me why time is doubled? 
Link to live version: http://najlepszekomisy.co.pl/

Thank you.

```js
var elem =
{
    map: document.getElementById("mapa"),
    panel: document.getElementById("right_panel"),
    games: document.getElementById("games"),
    draw: document.getElementById("draw"),
    points: document.getElementById("pointsGet"),
    timer: document.getElementById("timer")
};
(function intro()
{
    elem.games.addEventListener("click",function(e){
        if(e.target.tagName==="H4")
        {
            TweenMax.to(elem.games,1,{ease: Back.easeOut,top: -50,onComplete:function(){
            startGame(e.target.innerHTML);}})
        }
    },false)
})();

function startGame(hit)
{

  var gameElement =
    {
        mapa:0,
        clickListener:0,
        number:0,
        usingSet:4,
        timeNum:10
    };

    (function loadMap()
    {
        var mapOptions =
        {
            zoom: 7,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            zoomControl: true,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.95442214470796, 19.14093017578125)
        };
        gameElement.mapa = new google.maps.Map(elem.map, mapOptions);
        google.maps.event.addListener(gameElement.mapa,'idle',function()
        {
            TweenMax.to("#right_panel",2,{ease: Back.easeIn,right: 0,onComplete:function(){
                TweenMax.set(".anim_from_bottom", { display: 'block' });
                TweenMax.staggerFrom(".anim_from_bottom",0.5,{y:1600},0.2);
                google.maps.event.clearListeners(gameElement.mapa, 'idle');
                }});
        });
    })();
    elem.draw.addEventListener("click",function(){
        if(gameElement.number<gameElement.usingSet)
        {
        gameElement.number++;
        timer.time=gameElement.timeNum;
        timer.calcTime();
        gameElement.clickListener = google.maps.event.addListener(gameElement.mapa, "click", function (e) {
                addMarker(e.latLng.lng(), e.latLng.lat());

        });
        elem.draw.disabled=true;
    }else{result()}},false);

    function addMarker(lng,lat)
    {
        timer.stopTime();
        var opcjeMarkera =
        {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
            map: gameElement.mapa,
            title: hit

        };

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(opcjeMarkera);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(gameElement.clickListener);
        elem.draw.disabled=false;

    }

    var timer =
    {
        time: 0,
        startTime:0,
        calcTime:function()
        {
            elem.timer.className = "elem";
            elem.timer.innerHTML = timer.time;
            console.log(timer.time);
            if(timer.time===0){elem.timer.className = " ";clearTimeout(timer.startTime);}
            else
            {
                --timer.time;
                timer.startTime = setTimeout(timer.calcTime, 1000);
            }

        },
        stopTime:function()
        {
            clearTimeout(timer.startTime);
            elem.timer.className = " ";
            this.time=gameElement.timeNum;
        }
    };
    function result ()
        {
            console.log("koniec");
            gameElement.number=0;
            TweenMax.to("#right_panel",2,{ease: Back.easeIn,right: -300});
            TweenMax.to(elem.games,1,{ease: Back.easeOut,top: 50})

        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time your `H4` button is clicked it calls `startGame` function. Every time `startGame` function is called it adds one more event listener to the `Start` button, so start handler is called once when you play first time, twice the second time, thrice next time etc.

To avoid this you can:

- add event listener in `init` function (which is called once)
- remove event listeners before adding new one (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)
- use `onclick` property instead of .`addEventListener()` method if there is only one handler needed for this button

Comment: Thank you for answer but I don't understand one thing. In function "result" I added removeEventListener but still when I call "startGame", function adds another listener. Can you tell me why that removelistener doesn't remove listener permanently? Regards.

Comment: .removeEventListener() will only remove the given handler if you give it the exact same handler function, but you create a new anonymous function. You will need to do something like:

var handler = function() {...};
node.addEventListener('click', handler);
node.removeEventListener('click', handler);

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the calcTime function which includes this code:

```
 timer.startTime = setTimeout(timer.calcTime, 1000);
```

cannot be invoked while it is already running, because if it does, then another call to calcTime will be queued up causing the clock to tick twice as fast.